# Facebook meta property doesn't work

Tags: html, facebook, share, meta-tags

I get the thumbnail image to work, but the title and description is not the same as I write in.
Also the Title is my old title to the page. Does Facebook have some timeout on changing the material?

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mypage.se/images/mypic.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="My title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="I use UTF-8 ÅÄÖ" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facebook crawler does cache everything he comes along.
But I think you can override its cached data when using their debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Awesome! That solved it. I had no idea Facebook had a cache memory. I'll accept your answer in 5 min when the timeout has passed :)

Comment: facebook remembers everything.. ;)